# How to extract and verify google oAuth2.0 access token for middleware (nodejs and expressjs)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

hey i need help on for extracting oAuth2.0 access token and parsing it to my middleware for verification
i want to use two auth systems for my project which is firebase auth and  google sign in oAuth2.0 but my issue is i cant seem to figure out how to extract access token and verify it on my middleware here is mycode below to give you a picture:

signinprovider.js :

```
function signInOauth() {
  let oauth2Endpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

  let form = document.createElement('form')
  form.setAttribute("method", 'GET');
  form.setAttribute("action", oauth2Endpoint)
  
  let params = {
    "client_id": "gjfgjfgjfgjfg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000/profile",
    "response_type":"token",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
    "include_granted_scopes": 'true',
    'state': 'pass-through-value'
  }

  for(var p in params) {
    let input = document.createElement('input')
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
    input.setAttribute('name', p)
    input.setAttribute('value', params[p])
    form.appendChild(input)
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form)
  
  form.submit()
}

// Add onclick event to the Google Sign-In button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const googleSignInButton = document.getElementById('googleSignInButton');
  googleSignInButton.onclick = signInOauth;
});
```

and middleware/verifyToken.js :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/firestore');

const errorPageUrl = '/error';


// Middleware for verifying and handling session cookies and ID tokens
async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.session;
  const idToken = req.headers.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer ') ? req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1] : null;

  if (!token && !idToken) {
    return res.redirect('/error?status=401&message=The page you are looking for doesn\'t exist. please try searching for some other page, or return to our website Homepage.'); // No session cookie or ID token found, user is not authenticated
  }

  let decodedToken;
  try {
    if (token || idToken) {
      decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token, true); // Second parameter for checkRevoked
    } else {
      decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    }
    req.currentUser = decodedToken; // Attach the user data to the request object

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.redirect('/error?status=401&message=Session cookie or Token has expired'); // Session cookie or ID token is invalid or expired
  }
  console.log(decodedToken);

  next();
}

module.exports = { verifyToken };
```

and routes/pages.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const { verifyToken } = require("../middleware/verifyToken");
const router = express.Router();

// Profile route
router.get('/profile', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  const user = req.currentUser;
  
  if (!user) {
    return res.redirect('/error?status=401&message=The page you are looking for doesn\'t exist. please try searching for some other page, or return to our website Homepage.');
  }
  res.sendFile('profile.html', { root: './public/pages/accounts/' });
});
```

i tried alot of things i also tried writing a function to handle access token using urlParams still  wasnt able to get it working